# Unable to bring back terminal launcher in fedora

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora

Our office housing keeping guy sat on my linux (Fedora 7) system and somehow removed the main panel. By panel I mean where all the menus are there - Applications, Places, System etc. and contains a tab for every running application. I brought back the panel but now I don't see the terminal launcher and I can't find it anywhere. It used to be there in "Applications -> System Tools -> Terminal" but now the System Tools option itself is not present there.

System -> Preferences -> Look and Feel -> Main Menu. There one System option is unchecked but I can't check it and apply. I am logged in as root.

How do I bring it back? Please help. This is very irritating and weird. That guy doesn't even know what he has done so no use of asking him. :)

Comment: This is even more strange. No answers to any of my questions in superuser. Am I talking about rocket science in front of some villagers? Come on, if anything is not clear please ask me give some more details. I guess these questions are fit for superuser otherwise these would have been closed or migrated.

Comment: Don't bash the community, or we'll [quarter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanged,_drawn_and_quartered) you /saracasm. Apparently, we're not fans of GNOME.

Comment: Hey kiddo! you just learned that word in your literature class and thought about using it, didn't you? That quartering is such a barbaric thing... I never knew about it... Anyways, I was just trying to put some humor in what I observed. Have you seen that all my questions were not based on GNOME? The response of the superuser community is really very strange.

Comment: Yes, Yes & Yes :)

Comment: @Surge, new123456 - I no more work on the same system. So, can't check if the solutions provided by you work. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing the a GNOME configuration directory. They are:

- ~/.gnome
- ~/.gnome2

GNOME should autogenerate these when you delete them and log in again and the **System** menu should be part of the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the menubar on the panel, there is an 'Edit Menus' entry there, which will let you tweak the menu contents.